# Error while Iterating a Composite Image Collection over PCA analysis

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-mosaic, data-collection

I have created a composite image of Landsat 8 from the year 2014 to 2020, these are stacked images for summer season. Now while applying PCA analysis and extracting a particular band it is showing an error of:

> Layer error: Unknown variable references: [].

Can you help with the iteration?

```
var areaofinterest = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[77.15910143897746, 28.474337517697673],
      [77.15910143897746, 28.277991340697856],
      [77.41453356788371, 28.277991340697856],
      [77.41453356788371, 28.474337517697673]]], null, false);

var studyArea = areaofinterest
var stepList = ee.List.sequence(2014,2020);

var filterCollection = stepList.map(function(year){
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,11,1);
  var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,12,31);
  var composite_i = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
    .filterBounds(studyArea)
    .select('B2','B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','B10', 'B11')
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()).set('system:time_start',startDate);
  return composite_i;
});

var yearlyComposites = ee.ImageCollection(filterCollection);

function PCA(img, list){
  var pca8;

  var region = areaofinterest;
  Map.centerObject(region, 10);
  //Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(region, 0, 2), {}, 'Region');
  Map.addLayer(img, visParams, 'Original Image');

  var scale = 30;
  var bandNames = img.bandNames();
  
  var meanDict = img.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = img.subtract(means);

  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };

  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    var arrays = centered.toArray();

    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e9
    });
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);

    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);
    var principalComponents =         ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    return principalComponents
       .arrayProject([0])
       .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
       .divide(sdImage);
  };

  // Get the PCs at the specified scale and in the specified region
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);

  pca8 = pcImage.select([pcImage.bandNames().get(7).getInfo()]);

  var max = pca8.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), areaofinterest);
  var min = pca8.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), areaofinterest);

  var pca8 = pca8.expression('(pca8 - min)/(max - min)',{
    'pca8' : pca8.select('pc8'),
    'max' : max.getNumber('pc8'),
    'min' : min.getNumber('pc8'),
  }).rename('PCA');

  return img.addBands(pca8) 
}


yearlyComposites = yearlyComposites.map(function(image){
  return PCA(image);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.getInfo()` in a `.map()` call since `.getInfo()` is client-side and mapped functions exclusively run server-side.

To stay server-side convert the output from the get on the bandnames to an `ee.String`.

To do that instead of using `.get()` on the bandnames you can use `.getString()` or cast the result to a string. So either of these results should work:

```
var pca8 = pcImage.select([pcImage.bandNames().getString(7)])

var pca8 = pcImage.select([ee.String(pcImage.bandNames().get(7))])
```